# Short way of stating the 'amount of time the player spent playing the game'

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm developing a timer application that keeps track of duration of board game and also time spent by each player. I'm not sure how I can in a short form mark this time on the charts and in other places.

Should it be "player time" or "player play duration" - the latter being quite long for the chart axis title. Or maybe something else?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What **is** the "time spent by each player"? Is it time on the pitch (football, ice hockey...)? Is it time spent making moves (chess, draughts/checkers)? There may be a specialist term which might be better asked on a specialist Stack Exchange site for the game in question.

Comment: Good point. I don't know why I didn't include in the question. App is dedicated for boardgames so it's time spent making moves

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use *playtime* since it is easier to think of the term as representing the amount of *time* you *played* the game. 
I am generally a gamer myself, so when I think of the word *gameplay*, I think of the content of the game being played rather than the amount of time I spent playing it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with _playtime_.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply say:

> (each player's) *gameplay* time

Perhaps strangely, *gameplay* does not appear to be a word recognized by Merriam-Webster. However, it is recognized by [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gameplay):

> The features of a video game, such as its plot and the way it is played, as distinct from the graphics and sound effects.
>   *‘The first is the lack of additional characters that can join the party to affect the plot or gameplay.’*

*Gameplay* also has an entry at both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gameplay) and [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1911/gameplay).

It's normally used as a more generalized noun, but in ***gameplay*** *time*, it is used as an attributive noun.

For further reference, there is a utility called [*Gameplay Time Tracker*](https://www.gameplay-time-tracker.info/en/default.aspx).